# Subtitles throughout Drupal Site?

Tags: drupal, title, subtitle

I want to be able to enter TWO values everytime I create a "page", "block" or a "view". Those values must be "Title" and "Subtitle". Title is already built into all nodes, blocks and views. However, there is no "subtitle" or "title2" for any of them. It's easy to do this for a page using CCK, but I want a way to have it for views as well.

Is there perhaps a module that allows you to assign new values to blocks and views, similar to CCK for nodes? Or is there a subtitle module that does this? Any other advice on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention what version of drupal you were using. [Block Subtitle](http://drupal.org/project/block_subtitle) is a available for D6 only. For views, I would imagine that you could just place your subtitle in the header.

Comment: Drupal 6 is what I am using. :-) But block subtitle doesnt quite solve my views problem?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the [Block Subtitle module](http://drupal.org/project/block_subtitle) is what you need.